# Angular No provider for Clipboard

Tags: angular, clipboard

I am using Angular 9 and trying to use the Clipboard Module programmatically.

```
  constructor(
    private clipboard: Clipboard
  ) {}
```

It just wouldn't compile

it gives in the console the following.

```
NullInjectorError: No provider for Clipboard!
```

I added 'Clipboard' in the app.module.ts providers array. It is also not working

It is giving

```
zone-evergreen.js:659 Unhandled Promise rejection: Illegal constructor ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Illegal constructor
    at Object.factory (core.js:17177)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:17053)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:16803)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (core.js:36454)
    at Object.get (core.js:34091)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.js:5830)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You are not providing Clipboard, whatever it is (means: having it in the providers array of the corresponding module). Do you like to specify it? Do you mean the CDK Clipboard?

Comment: Yeah the one comes with Angular CDK. I edited the question.

Comment: That's my question. What should I register in the providers?

Answer (score 16):

Make sure that you import the correct 'Clipboard'

```
import { Clipboard } from '@angular/cdk/clipboard';

constructor(private clipboard: Clipboard) {

}
```

then use this function

```
 private copyToClipboard(str:string) {
    const pending = this.clipboard.beginCopy(str);

      let remainingAttempts = 3;
      const attempt = () => {
        const result = pending.copy();
        if (!result && --remainingAttempts) {
          setTimeout(attempt);
        } else {
          // Remember to destroy when you're done!
          pending.destroy();
        }
      };
      attempt();
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you forgot to include the import for ClipBoard (in the file where you injected ClipBoard in the constructor):

```js
import {Clipboard} from "@angular/cdk/clipboard"
```

Because ClipBoard exists also on windows, but it's not the same API:

```js
interface Clipboard extends EventTarget {
    readText(): Promise<string>;
    writeText(data: string): Promise<void>;
}
```

So you won't have any errors if you forgot the import.
But when Angular will try to inject it, it won't find one provider for that.

Comment: Thank you very much! That saved my Day :D

Answer (score 3):

You need to import the `ClipboardModule` which registers the `Clipboard` as a provider.

See the stripped example below. I left out everything else you would put in your module to just focus on the `ClipboardModule`.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {ClipboardModule} from '@angular/cdk/clipboard';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ClipboardModule]
})
export class AppModule {}()
```

Comment: I tried this. I got this error

core.js:6210 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[Clipboard -> Clipboard -> Clipboard]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Clipboard!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[Clipboard -> Clipboard -> Clipboard]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Clipboard!

Comment: @MissakBoyajian are you using multiple modules? If so you need to import the `ClipboardModule` in the module where you are trying to use it, not just in the root module.

Comment: No just 1 module. app.module.ts.

Comment: If you are using `ng build --watch=true` or `ng serve` then stop the cli console and then restart it.

Comment: @MissakBoyajian  can you recreate the problem using https://stackblitz.com ?

Comment: I'll inform you once I do that